# Probabilistic Record Linkage

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, probabilistic-programming

**Record linkage** is the task of identifying which records from different **data sources** refer to the same entities. Without the **common identification key** among different databases, this task could be performed by comparison of corresponding fields (containing the information for identification) in records to link. To do this, many record linkage methods have been proposed in the last decades, like "**WINKLER** method" and "**DUVALL** method" among others.

There is an R package "fastLink" which implements "**FELLEGI-SUNTER**" algorithm but it does not implement **WINKLER** method!!

My question is : Could some one please provide references for either of these methods? And perhaps any **packages** in **R, Python, Matlab, or SAS** that could be helpful?

Comment: You can check R packages like reclin and RecordLinkage. These packages offer both deterministic and probabilistic methods for data linkage. In Python too, there's a record linkage toolkit that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

The R package `stringdist` can calculate various string distances based on edits
(Damerau-Levenshtein, Hamming, Levenshtein, optimal sting alignment), qgrams (qgram, cosine, jaccard distance) or heuristic metrics (Jaro, Jaro-Winkler). This package doesn't do matching on its own but can be used to calculate string distances that you can use in a probabilistic matching framework.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf

Comment: thank you but what i need is doing Record Linkage algorithms like "WINKLER method" or "DUVAL method". i have already worked "FELLEGI-SUNTER" method but this algorithm has a lot of limits...